# Save and return to cursor in CLI not working

Tags: python, ansi-escape

I am attempting a type ahead / predictive typing effect in a python cli. I am referencing the following list of ANSI escape codes: https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797

Looking at the "Cursor Controls" section there are two commands for saving and returning to a cursor position. I want to couple that with deleting so that when typing it adds the character to the rest and clears the type ahead effect. So I currently have:

```py
import readchar
import sys

print("Reading input: ", end="")
sys.stdout.flush()
s = ""
while True:
    # Goto saved position
    print("\x1B 8", end="")
    sys.stdout.flush()

    char = readchar.readchar()
    # remove to end / clear effect
    print("\x1B[0K", end="")
    sys.stdout.flush()

    if char == "\r":
        break

    print(char, end="")
    # save the cursor position
    
    ahead_text = "#"
    print("\x1B 7" + ahead_text, end="")
    sys.stdout.flush()

    s += char

print("\nresult was", s)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

However on windows terminal it is not clearing the temporary ahead of time text `#`:
[image]

Do these commands work? Is there an alternative ANSI sequence?

Comment: Typo.  You are inserting a space in your codes.  There should be no space: `"\x1B8"` and `"\x1B7"`.  The space in that page is just to separate the word "ESC".

Comment: @TimRoberts ah well caught, that fixed it!